# what does Swift type safety mean by this?

Tags: swift

this was on official apple website(swift tutorials)
"Swift’s type safety prevents non-Boolean values from being substituted for Bool"

```
let i = 1
if i
{
    // this example will not compile, and will report an error
}

let i = 1
if i == 1 {
    // this example will compile successfully
}
```

question: 
what security or safety language gets by doing this? please explain with example..

Answer (score 2):

When Objective-C was conceived in the 80s, its designers decided to make ObjC a strict superset of C, i.e. any valid C code is also valid in ObjC. C at that time doesn't have a boolean type - anything other than 0 is true. On top of that, the assignment operator in C also has a return value. The following are all valid in C:

```
int a, b;
a = (b = 2); // Now both a and b are 2

if (a) {
    // What you are really testing for is a != 0
}

if (a = 4) {
    // You just changed a to 4 and the true block will execute 
    // Perhaps what you really meant was to test for a == 4?
}
```

When designing Swift, Apple decided to do away with the patterns. An `if` statement must check on a boolean condition:

```
if a { }       // invalid, you must test for a boolean condition
if a != 0  { } // ok

if (a = 4) { } // invalid, assignment does not return
if a == 4  { } // ok
```

Answer (score -1):

In objective-c, an int that is greater or less than 0 would be considered as true and int that has a value of 0 would be considered false if you would to use it in that context.

E.g. In objective-c

```
int i = 1;
if (i) {
// this would be executed
}

if (i == 1) {
// this would too be executed
}
```

If you know exactly what you are doing you wouldn't have any problems, but imaging that you make a mistake and write `if i { ... }`. It would be really hard to find that mistake since the compiler wouldn't complain.